# Rails: How can I make an object available in all views?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a `search` object which is created in my Galleries controller and displayed in my Galleries View:

**app/controllers/galleries_controller.rb**

```
class GalleriesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @galleries = Gallery.all
    @search = Search.new
  end
```

This object represents a search bar. I want to move the search bar into my `layouts/application.html.erb` view and make it available on all pages in the header. This would require me to make the `search` object globally available, and I am not sure how to do that. I tried sticking in ApplicationController and thought that would make it available in all views since everything inherence from there, but it didn't work. How can I make an object available in all views?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it with a `before_action` (aka. `before_filter`) in the `ApplicationController`, from which all your controllers should inherit.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :make_search

  def make_search
    @galleries = Gallery.all
    @search = Search.new
  end
end
```

This will make the function run before every action.

You can use `skip_before_action :make_search` to disable it in a specific controller, if you need to, or `skip_before_action :make_search, only: :index` to disable it for only the `index` action for a controller.

If you only want this for a few controllers, you could define `make_search` in the `ApplicationController`, and put the `before_action :make_search` in the controllers for which you want to enable it...

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your `ApplicationController`:

```
def search
  @search ||= Search.new
end

def galleries
  @galleries ||= Gallery.all
end
```

You then use the function (`search`) in your views instead if the instance variable `@search`); the `||=` makes sure the code is executed only once (thus saving database queries).

Answer (score 0):

You can make the object globally available by breaking MVC and just create the object inside the view:

```
    <% @search = Search.new %>
    <%= form_for @search do |form| %>
      <%= form.text_field :query, placeholder: "Search for a Picture" %>
    <% end %>
```